# How Do I return a value out a GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I currently have a GUI that keeps a running string that I would like to return when the GUI is exited. I create a class of the GUI in a "runner" class and I would then like to use the string. Is there anyway to return this string out of my GUI?

```
public class Gui {

    //running string is edited by an action listener of the gui.
    String runningString = "";

    ...
}
```

OTHER CLASS FILE

```
class Runner {

    JFrame thisGui = new GUI;

    //user uses GUI
    thisstring = runningString; // (How do i get running String?)

    ...
}
```

Comment: What's on the receiving end?  How will you capture this output, whatever it is?  And how will you go on to use it?

Comment: the output is stored as a string in the GUI class. I'm wondering how to get it out like Gui.getThisString(); but you apparently can't do that even when you make that method in the GUI class

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Basically, Java classes will not be destroyed unless it is a inter
   processes. You make your `java.lang.String` have `public`, `static`
   scope to access from that GUI class.
2. Or else, you can have a `set()` method to write a string in different
   class before or on exiting out of the GUI, unless the application crashes.

For example:

```
myframe.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent winEvt) {
        updateZonas();
        //db.close();
        //System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of "inter processes"?

Comment: Ah, thank you. It looks like for the duration of the JVM, "Types loaded through the bootstrap class loader will always be reachable and never be unloaded."—[Unloading of Types](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype6.html)